# How to use QXmpp server_example?

Tags: qt, xmpp

I've compiled Qxmpp server_example successfully, but yet dunno
how to connect a client to that server - Example from Qxmpp library. Can anybody suggest smth, I'll be grateful for that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an XMPP server that you can connect to? You can setup one locally by using one of these servers: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

Ideally, you'd want to have two instances of the client software on two different physical machines/virtual machines so you can test that the messaging works between two users.